# How to replace more than one special character from a string

Tags: regex, string, c#-4.0

I have a string i.e. as given below.

```
 string s = @"Test1212ULL99|H|||F~~~
NTE|||      Reference Range~  Negative~  Elevated Antibody Level~~
FT1||||2015072100||NA|^^DMHC100^STDNULL99^I9
MSH|^~\&|Cnoss CA||||901834|P|2.4|||NE|NE|||||CALINX_1.3~
PID|2||MRN45161510^^^^PT~1860664CASANOVA AVE&820^^MONTEREY^CA^93940^^H||(831) 917-1541";

string replacementString = "\r";
 string result = Regex.Replace(s, @"~~\r", replacementString);
```

I have to replace all the ~ sign from last of row only not from mid of the row. E.g line 1 contains three ~ sign in last and line two and three contains 2 and 1 ~ sign in last.

Can any one tell me how i can achieve this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and Sweet. (If you just need substitution and not capturing `~`)

```
~+?$
```

This will remove all the `~` from last of line only and not from middle. Works for multiline string as well.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cP8lG0/1

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
~+(?=[\r\n])
```

This will replace `~` from the end of string only.Replace by `empty string`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/13